# convert mysql table to DynamoDB

Tags: mysql, amazon-dynamodb

I'm new to DynamoDB and I'm trying to get the hang of it but I'm not getting how to maintain relation in single table DynamoDB.

Basically I am executing script & dynamically adding data into table.

First I am adding entry in run master & take id from it & add multiple entries detailedruninfo along with run_id from master table. below are mysql table data:

```
run_master table (id is PK)
+----+-------------------------------+
| id | user_id |  add_date           |  
+----+---------+---------------------+
| 1  | 1       |2022-09-23 11:04:06  | 
+----+---------+---------------------+
| 2  | 1       |2021-09-25 01:37:41  |
+----+---------+---------------------+
| 3  | 2       |2021-10-03 06:29:16  |
+----+---------+---------------------+

run_details table (run_id is FK)
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| id |  run_id | track_name |  status |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| 1  | 1       | track1     | fail    |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| 2  | 1       | track2     | pass    |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| 3  | 1       | track3     | fail    |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| 4  | 2       | us         | pass    |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
| 5  | 3       | it         | pass    |
+----+---------+------------+---------+
```

I know if run master table entries are fixed then I can directly add column in run_details table but I am inserting data into loop for both table.

how to create table in dynamoDb and what would be the query if I want to get all records from  run_details by Run Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here that the combination of `run_id` and `add_date` is unique, for that reason I have used those as PK and SK respectively.

The below table allows you to get all runs for a given `run_id` by using a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) operation and providing the run_id.

`id` is not needed here, as it serves no purpose.

```
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| run_id | add_date             | track_name |  status | user_id |
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| 1      | 2022-09-23 11:04:06  | track1     | fail    |  1      |
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| 1      | 2022-09-23 11:04:06  | track2     | pass    |  1      |
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| 1      | 2022-09-23 11:04:06  | track3     | fail    |  1      |
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| 2      | 2022-09-23 11:04:06  | us         | pass    |  2      |
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
| 3      | 2022-09-23 11:04:06  | it         | pass    |  3      |
+--------+----------------------+------------+---------+---------+
```

You can also create an index on `user_id` should you wish to get all runs by user etc...